# Moving/aliasing an npm package that exists

Tags: npm

I have a rather popular package that has been published on npm for a while. I'd like to rename it to another package name I have and treat it as an alias similar to when you rename a Github repository.

Is there a process for doing this and will it retain all my previously downloads (which are critical for my recognition, trust and scale of my project)?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to rename your package, you will need to unpublish it and then republish it under the new name. This will reset your download count, but your previous users will still be able to install the old version of the package using the old name.

For example, if your old package was called "foo" and you want to rename it to "bar", you would first need to unpublish "foo":

```
npm unpublish foo
```

Then you would need to republish "bar" with the same contents as "foo":

```
npm publish bar
```

Comment: So there's no way to convert your current patch to another package name and retain all the downloads? :-(